# Why is console.error a method instead of a function?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am using [ES6 Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) heavily these days. As such, it is easy to lose track of an exception if you don't specify an `onRejected` function:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(doCrazyThingThatMightThrowAnException());
}).then(function(result) {
  return performDangerousTranformation(result);
});
```

It would be really nice if I could add a few bytes using `catch()` to make sure an exception makes it into the console:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(doCrazyThingThatMightThrowAnException());
}).then(function(result) {
  return performDangerousTranformation(result);
}).catch(console.error);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work because `console.error` is a method rather than a function. That is, you need to specify the receiver, `console`, when invoking `console.error()`. You can verify this for yourself fairly easy in the browser console:

```
> console.error('err');
prints err
> var f = console.error;
> f('err');
throws Illegal invocation exception
```

This means that adding my `catch()` handler is a bit more verbose:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(doCrazyThingThatMightThrowAnException());
}).then(function(result) {
  return performDangerousTranformation(result);
}).catch(function(error) { console.error(error); });
```

Admittedly, it's a bit better in ES6:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(doCrazyThingThatMightThrowAnException());
}).then(function(result) {
  return performDangerousTranformation(result);
}).catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

But it would be nice to avoid the extra typing. What's worse is that if you use `catch(console.error)` today, your exception gets silently ignored, which is exactly the problem you are trying to solve! Is there anything fundamental to how `console.error()` works that it needs to be a method?

Comment: `console.error.bind(console)`

Comment: I guess this depends on the implementation, and that you _may_ find implementations that works "as a function"

Comment: Why don't you just make a function for the errors?
`var err = function(){console.error.apply(console, arguments);}` Did I miss something?

Comment: @torazaburo That's about as verbose as the ES6 approach. Still more than I would like to have to type. Admittedly, your suggestion does not introduce a new scope.

@Volune I might, but Chrome/V8/Node makes it a method, which is my primary use case.

@ThanasisGrammatopoulos Yes, you missed the part where I am trying to make things less verbose. I use Promises all over the place and I don't want to have to keep a global `err` around because I do this a lot.

Comment: If your question is how to easily log rejected promises, rather than "why console.log is a method instead of a function", you might consider changing the title of the question. I mean, if you're really asking the question as titled, then there's just one "correct" answer, which is, well, that's what it is.

Comment: @Volune: Indeed, on node.js it is known that the console methods don't use `this` internally and thus can be made to "work as a function"

Comment: No, it's not just about rejected promises. This could apply to console.log/console.error and any function that takes a callback-like argument. I'm trying to understand why browser implementors would design things this way and/or if they could be motivated to change it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this behavior has been changed in Node: https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/025f53c306d91968b292051404aebb8bf2adb458.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the Promise object, if your religion permits:

```
Promise.prototype.catchLog = function() {
    return this.catch(
        function(val) {
            console.log("Promise has rejected with reason", val);
            throw val;          // continue with rejected path
        }
    );
};
```

Then

```
function crazy() { throw 99; }

Promise.resolve()
    .then(crazy)
    .catchLog();

>>> Promise has rejected with reason 99
```

You requested being able to add logging for rejections with "a few bytes"; with this it's three (L-o-g) on the end of `catch`.